# GNU ld does not handle ORIGIN processing correctly; is there a workaround?

Tags: linker, gnu, ld

In Solaris, I link some stuff as follows (using Sun Studio; under the hood it uses the Solaris linker, not GNU):

```
CC -shared (other flags) -R'$ORIGIN/../lib/' -o /buildpath/lib/libmylib1.so
CC -shared (other flags) -R'$ORIGIN/../lib/' -lmylib1 -o /buildpath/lib/libmylib2.so
CC (various flags) -R'$ORIGIN/../lib/' -lmylib2 -o /buildpath/bin/somebinary
```

... and it links the final binary just fine.

When I attempt to do this in Linux with GNU `ld` (again using Sun Studio as the compiler driver) the shared objects link fine, but `somebinary` fails to link because it can't find libmylib1.so.

When I run the 3rd line through strace, it attempts to open a file whose path has the literal (un-expanded) string `$ORIGIN` in it.

I've come across a number of other questions touching on this topic.  The only workaround I've seen is to use relative paths, but that requires that you execute the binary from a fixed location -- that is, it checks relative to `` `pwd` `` instead of the binary's location.

Before anyone chimes in with the usual comment about `$ORIGIN` being unsafe/insecure -- that isn't a concern in our environment, and I don't care to hear comments about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I have to do it this way, though I'm not sure what side effects this may have just yet as I'm unfamiliar with the `-rpath-link` flag:

```
CC -shared (other flags) -R'$ORIGIN/../lib/' -o /buildpath/lib/libmylib1.so
CC -shared (other flags) -R'$ORIGIN/../lib/' -lmylib1 -o /buildpath/lib/libmylib2.so
CC (various flags) -R'$ORIGIN/../lib/' -Wl,-rpath-link,/buildpath/lib/ -lmylib2 -o /buildpath/bin/somebinary
```

With the few tests I did, I learned the following:

- `$ORIGIN` does not get expanded at all by GNU `ld`, whether in `-rpath` or `-rpath-link` flags

  - `ld.so` will expand it fine
- `-rpath-link` is the very first set of paths searched, before `-rpath`, `DT_*PATH`, `LD_*_PATH`, etc.